# android: how to save my user interface and get it back after reboot?

Tags: android

Sorry I am totally new to Android

My application has a very simple GUI (2 checkboxes, 3 textiputs).
**I want to save the value of these widgets (checkboxes, textinputs), so after I reboot my andorid they keep their values.**

I guess I can use some local stoarge or db storage, but I am not fluent enough to pick up the fastest/better solution to do that?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/data-storage/index.html) for storing data in Android

Since you are working with a small amount of data to be saved, I'd recommend option #1: **Saving Key-Value Sets** aka `SharedPreferences`

You can do it as follows

**Writing to Shared Preferences**

```
SharedPreferences shp = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shp.edit();
editor.putString("YourPreferenceName", yourVariable);
editor.commit();
```

**Reading from Shared Preferences**

```
SharedPreferences shp = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String yourVariable= shp.getString"YourPreferenceName", "default");
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the values in [`SharedPreferences`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). Alternatively, read the page on [Settings screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html) (which use `SharedPreference`s behind the scenes).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PreferenceFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html) which can automagically store those values in the [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). Here is a good [tutorial](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/07/example-of-using-preferencefragment.html). If thats all you need to store locally, using `PreferenceFragment` will save you time coding saving/retrieving/displaying those values from `SharedPreferences` yourself.